# Get frequency result in 1/(units of time)

Tags: google-search, google-calculator

As a developer, I sometimes want to estimate how long a particular process takes. So I'll let it run a while, take the number of items it completed, and divide by how long it took. So if process X completed 500 items in 2 hours, I can plug it into Google's search engine like so:

```
500/(2 hours)
```

to [get the rate](https://www.google.com/search?q=500%2F%282+hours%29). However, the result is in [Hertz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hertz):

[image: 500/(2 hours) in Hertz]

1/s is not a particularly useful unit for these quantities. I'd like this one to be in 1/minutes. However, [adding `in 1/minutes` to the end](https://www.google.com/search?ei=y3U4WvfAEtLw_Aa9_bGICA&q=500%2F%282+hours%29+in+1%2Fminutes) just confuses Google and prevents it from calculating anything:

[image: in 1/minutes confuses Google]

Google calculator behaves similarly for 1/hours.

How can I get control the units of frequency?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `in 1/minutes`, [use `in minutes^-1`](https://www.google.com/search?q=500%2F%282+hours%29+in+minutes%5E-1):

[image: Calculated in 1/minutes using minutes^-1]

Google recognizes this as a unit and converts to it, unlike `1/minutes`. It might take a bit of getting use to, but it gives you the quantity you want.